# How do I properly invoke a subroutine that takes 2 subroutine references?

Tags: perl, subroutine

Imagine this subroutine:

```
sub test(&&)
{
    my $cr1 = shift;
    my $cr2 = shift;
    $cr1->();
    $cr2->();
}
```

I know I can call it like: `test(\&sub1,\&sub2)`, but how can I call it like:

```
test { print 1 },{ print 2 };
```

If I say that the subroutine takes only one `&`, than sending a block will work. I don't know how to make it work with 2.

If I try to run it like that, I get:

```
Not enough arguments for main::test at script.pl line 38, near "},"
```

EDIT: is there no way of invoking without `sub`?

Comment: Why? (do you want to avoid using the 'sub' keyword)

Comment: I'd like it to look more `DSL`-ish.

Comment: Good luck with the source filter, I guess :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
test(sub { print 1 }, sub { print 2 });
```

Comment: You _have_ to do it like this. Otherwise it will seem to perl like you are trying to pass two hash-refs.

Comment: I want to invoke them without sub. Both of them.

Comment: sub is Perl's way of writing an anonymous subroutine. So either use a ref to a named sub, or an expression that evaluates to one (e.g. variable whose value is a subref), or use an anonymous sub - in the latter case, you will use `sub{}`

Comment: "the fattest girl in the world" is the commonest meaning I saw.  There's also "thank freaking goodness it's the weekend" (polite form).  Neither makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Fastest Gun In The West :)
Meaning, you beat my nearly identical answer by <1 minute, IIRC

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-solved :)

Answer (score 12):

You need to explicitly say

```
test( sub { print 1 }, sub { print 2 } );
```

or

```
test { print 1 } sub { print 2 };
```

The implicit "sub" is only available for the first argument.  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes:

> An &  requires an anonymous subroutine, which, if passed as the first argument, does not require the sub keyword or a subsequent comma.

Some things use an extra word in there to fake it:

```
test { print 1 } against { print 2 };

sub against (&) { $_[0] }
sub test (&@) { ... }
```

but I've never liked that much.

Comment: So there's no way of achieving this without a `source filter`?

Comment: @Geo: Pretend source filters don't exist.  Forget you ever heard of them.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the following code in one of my programs:

```
sub generate($$$$)
{
    my ($paramRef, $waypointCodeRef, $headerRef,
        $debugCodeRef) = @_;
...
   &$headerRef();
...
       my $used = &$waypointCodeRef(\%record);
```

And I call it with

```
CreateDB::generate(\%param, \&wayPointCode, \&doHeader, \&debugCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to bend the syntax more then take look at [`Devel::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Declare/)

Examples of modules that use [`Devel::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Declare/):

- [`MooseX::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Declare/)       ([GitHub repo](http://github.com/rafl/moosex-declare))
- [`Test::Class::Sugar`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Class-Sugar/) ([GitHub repo](http://github.com/pdcawley/test-class-sugar))
- [`PerlX::MethodCallWithBlock`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PerlX-MethodCallWithBlock/) ([GitHub repo](http://github.com/gugod/PerlX-MethodCallWithBlock))

Full list of [modules on CPAN dependant](http://cpants.perl.org/dist/used_by/Devel-Declare) on Devel::Declare can be found via [`CPANTS`](http://cpants.perl.org/)

Here is example from [Test::Class::Sugar pod](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Class-Sugar/lib/Test/Class/Sugar.pm):

```
use Test::Class::Sugar;

testclass exercises Person {
    # Test::Most has been magically included

    startup >> 1 {
        use_ok $test->subject;
    }

    test autonaming {
        is ref($test), 'Test::Person';
    }

    test the naming of parts {
        is $test->current_method, 'test_the_naming_of_parts';
    }

    test multiple assertions >> 2 {
        is ref($test), 'Test::Person';
        is $test->current_method, 'test_multiple_assertions';
    }
}

Test::Class->runtests;
```

And here is something sexy from [PerlX::MethodCallWithBlock pod](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PerlX-MethodCallWithBlock/lib/PerlX/MethodCallWithBlock.pm):

```
use PerlX::MethodCallWithBlock;

Foo->bar(1, 2, 3) {
  say "and a block";
};
```

Devel::Declare is a much more robust and saner way of contorting your Perl code compared to using a source filter like [`Filter::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Filter-Simple/).

Here is a [video](http://yapc.tv/2008/lpw/matt-trout-acme-yorkshire/) from its author which may help a bit more.

/I3az/

Comment: From the Devel::Declare docs: "Devel::Declare can install subroutines called declarators which locally take over Perl's parser, allowing the creation of new syntax."  I don't really understand how it works, but it is not a source filter.